# How do I make a user control display as pop up in windows 8.1 c# and xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I have a page that displays list of items. How do I make a user control to display detailed information about the item that is clicked (selected) in c# xaml.

If anyone can also suggest link to either a blog post or article that explains how to do this in details

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not the kind of questing SO is for, I'll answer anyway:

What you are looking for is probably a `flyout`. You can read a quickstart on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx)

**EXAMPLE**
You can add the flyout to an other UIElement with the `AttachedFlyout` attached property:

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrd">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout x:Name="MainFlt">
            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop2}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop3}"/>
                <Button Content="Close" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <ListView x:Name="MainLvw" SelectionChanged="MainLvw_SelectionChanged" Background="DeepSkyBlue">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop2}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop3}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And then in the code-behind, you call `FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout()` to show the flyout:

```
private void MainLvw_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var sndr = (ListView)sender;
    var item = (SampeClass)sndr.SelectedItem;
    RootGrd.DataContext = item;
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(RootGrd);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainFlt.Hide();
}
```

You can find an example solution on my github, which shows this implemented: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jonstodle/SOFlyoutSample)

Comment: Yeah, the article was helpful, but How do I make a pop up for data template for a ListView so that when an item is clicked I can display the pop up to display details for every item clicked